# Procedure of tranmission of original virus

Tags: virus

If   website A is having a video with a virus, then if we watch that video through another website B (like  dirpy dot com or getaudiofromvideo dot com), is there mechanism for the virus from website A  to reach our computer? We are not watching website A, we are watching it through website B, then what is the procedure through which the virus will reach our computer?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a flash video that's malicious, and your flash player is vulnerable to that particular attack, than it does not matter where it comes from and where you watch it. It's enough to play it to give access to your PC to the attacker.

Comment: Not just Flash, either. It could, for example, exploit a buffer overflow in the video player.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Indeed. While it can sometimes be difficult to believe, Flash is not the only browser technology known for its generous contributions to Mitre's CVE database.